# Any sense of buying Saab 9-3 1.9?

Tags: saab

Saab is now in bankrupt so it may be difficult to get parts for maintenance in the future. **So is there any sense of buying the Saab?**

I am thinking between [Volkswagen Passat](http://fin.auto24.ee/used/1076454) and [Saab 9-3 1.9](http://fin.auto24.ee/used/1373555).
Both are diesel and manual gear. These are two cars are only examples in the links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sense at all. You will have a terrible time finding any parts for it. My coworker had a very nice Saab last year, until a thief broke one of his windows. He searched high and low for a new window, and even if one could be found, it would have been overpriced. In the end, the Saab was replaced with a different car simply because of a broken window. Imagine if you needed an engine part. No dice.

Comment: Orphan cars are tough.  Sometimes someone will pick up the design and start making parts for them.  Sometimes not.  It's a roll of the dice.  Smart money is to stay with something factory supported.  Worst case if stuck with an orphan that you love, you can have parts made, or adapt parts from other cars to fit (unless in some crazy community that doesn't allow that).  That of course, will come at a cost both in time and money...

Answer (score 5):

Saab Automobile Parts AB was not included in the sale of Saab Automobile AB. It is now in the ownership of Swedish National Dept Office.

> - Saab Automobile Parts AB is not included in the sale of Saab Automobile AB
> - The parts company continues to serve Saab customers globally with Saab Genuine Parts and aftersales service and also to expand its logistics operations
> - The Swedish National Debt Office announced that they intend to take over the ownership of Saab Automobile Parts AB

http://www.saabparts.com/en/international/the-company/news/latest-news/newsroom/?nrpid=4335

Answer (score 3):

If the question involved a brand that sold more units worldwide and had a history of using the same parts for many years I would go for the Saab if it was what I really wanted. I don't know many people who rely solely on the dealer for parts of seven year old cars. Most go to the aftermarket or used for routine wear and crash items. If 2007 was the last year Saab or anyone else used a particular switch or body part it will most likely be unavailable seven years later from the dealer. If Saabs were a more popular brand the answer might be different as the aftermarket would take up where the factory left off. I know in my area of the U.S. Saab parts were rare when they made them. Since it is a Saab I would agree with @hillsons